# How to concatenate multiple columns in PySpark with a separator?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `pyspark Dataframe`, I would like to join 3 columns.

```
id |  column_1   | column_2    | column_3
--------------------------------------------
1  |     12      |   34        |    67
--------------------------------------------
2  |     45      |   78        |    90
--------------------------------------------
3  |     23      |   93        |    56
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to join the 3 columns : `column_1, column_2, column_3` in only one adding between there value `"-"`

Expect result:

```
id |  column_1   | column_2    | column_3    |   column_join
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  |     12      |     34      |     67      |   12-34-67
-------------------------------------------------------------
2  |     45      |     78      |     90      |   45-78-90
-------------------------------------------------------------
3  |     23      |     93      |     56      |   23-93-56
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I do it in pyspark ?
Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit

df = df.withColumn("column_join", concat(col("column_1"), lit("-"), col("column_2"), lit("-"), col("column_3")))
```

Use `concat` to concatenate all the columns with the `-` separator, for which you will need to use `lit`.

If it doesn't directly work, you can use `cast` to change the column types to string, `col("column_1").cast("string")`

**UPDATE**:

Or you can use a more dynamic approach using a built-in function [`concat_ws`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws)

> pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws(sep, *cols)
>
> ```
> Concatenates multiple input string columns together into a single string column, using the given separator.
>
> >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('abcd','123')], ['s', 'd'])
> >>> df.select(concat_ws('-', df.s, df.d).alias('s')).collect()
> [Row(s=u'abcd-123')]
> ```

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws

concat_columns = ["column_1", "column_2", "column_3"]
df = df.withColumn("column_join", concat_ws("-", *[F.col(x) for x in concat_columns]))
```

Comment: please I need to your help if you have a suggestion about this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197109/looking-if-string-contain-a-sub-string-in-differents-dataframes?noredirect=1#comment104618006_59197109

Comment: @verojoucla Please follow pault's comment on that question. Your answer is literally answered already

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I asked a new question, but for looking on my solution, can you have a look at please, I just want to create a new column in each dataframe that contain a monotonically_increasing_id, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59211575/how-to-find-an-optimized-join-between-2-different-dataframes-in-spark

Comment: Do you have some idea about this question please ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931770/sum-of-column-values-pyspark
thanks

Comment: Great answer thank you! Regarding the dynamic answer, what does the `*` signify?

Comment: @ocean800 It unpacks the list that we are creating in the square braces.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `generic/dynamic` way of doing this, instead of `manually` concatenating it. All we need is to specify the columns that we need to concatenate.

```
# Importing requisite functions.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf

# Creating the DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,12,34,67),(2,45,78,90),(3,23,93,56)],['id','column_1','column_2','column_3'])
```

Now, specifying the list of columns we want to concatenate, separated by `-`.

```
list_of_columns_to_join = ['column_1','column_2','column_3']
```

Finally, creating a [`UDF`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf). Mind it, `UDF` based solutions are implicitly slower.

```
def concat_cols(*list_cols):
    return '-'.join(list([str(i) for i in list_cols]))

concat_cols = udf(concat_cols)
df = df.withColumn('column_join', concat_cols(*list_of_columns_to_join))
df.show()
+---+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| id|column_1|column_2|column_3|column_join|
+---+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|  1|      12|      34|      67|   12-34-67|
|  2|      45|      78|      90|   45-78-90|
|  3|      23|      93|      56|   23-93-56|
+---+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
```