# How to find an optimized join between 2 different dataframes in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `2 different datasets,` I would like to join them, but there is no easy way to do it because they don't have a common column and the crossJoin not good solution when we use a bigdata. I already asked the question on stackoverflow, but really I couldn't find an optimized solution to join them. My question on stackoverflow is: [looking if String contain a sub-string in differents Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197109/looking-if-string-contain-a-sub-string-in-differents-dataframes?noredirect=1#comment104618006_59197109)

I saw these solution bellow but I didn't find a good way for my case.
[Efficient string suffix detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481681/efficient-string-suffix-detection)
[Efficient string suffix detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481681/efficient-string-suffix-detection)
[Efficient string matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938672/efficient-string-matching-in-apache-spark)

Today, I found a funny solution :) I'm not sure if it will be work, but let's try.

I add a new column in `df_1` to be contain numbering of lines.

Example df_1:

```
name    | id
----------------
abc     | 1232
----------------
azerty  | 87564
----------------
google  | 374856
----------------
```

new df_1:

```
name    | id       | new_id
----------------------------
abc     | 1232     |  1
----------------------------
azerty  | 87564    |  2
----------------------------
google  | 374856   |  3
----------------------------
explorer| 84763    |  4
----------------------------
```

The same for df_2:

Example df_2:

```
adress    |
-----------
UK        |
-----------
USA       |
-----------
EUROPE    |
-----------
```

new df_2:

```
adress    | new_id
-------------------
UK        |   1
-------------------
USA       |   2
-------------------
EUROPE    |   3
-------------------
```

Now, I have a common column between the 2 dataframes, I can do a left join using a `new_id` as `key`.
My question, is this solution efficient ? 
How can I add `new_id` columns in each dataframe with numbering of line ?

Comment: For second question, I guess you are looking for `monotonically_increasing_id()` ?

Comment: @chlebek Yes, as shown in my example, if I add a new rows should new_id should be increase by one.

Comment: @chlebek do you have an idea how do it please ?

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 
val new_df_2 = df_2.withColumn("new_id", monotonically_increasing_id())`

Comment: I used your solution, it seems work well, but I didn't understand why idx value is different, in df_1 for example is created it from 0 value, that what I need, but in df_2, is started from 8589934592.

Comment: I forgot that it isn't consequential, you can try `row_number` window function,
`df_2.withColumn("new_id",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy(lit(1))))`

Answer (score 0):

As the Spark is Lazy Evaluation ,it means that the execution will not start until an action is triggered .
So what you can do is simply call spark context createdataframe function and pass list of selected columns from df1 and df2 . It will create a new dataframe as you need.

e.g. `df3 = spark.createDataframe([df1.select(''),df2.select('')])`

Upvote if works

Comment: AttributeError: 'SparkSession' object has no attribute 'createDataframe' I got this error

Comment: the variable spark here is of spark context object .
And in your code its of spark session object .
you need to use 'spark context object'.createDataframe([df1.select(''),df2.select('')])